# filtrar datos especificos de un array

Tags: array

```
const ovejas = [
    { name: 'Noa', color: 'azul' },
    { name: 'Euge', color: 'rojo' },
    { name: 'Navidad', color: 'rojo' },
    { name: 'Ki Na Ma', color: 'rojo'}
  ]

  let ovejasFiltradas = ovejas.filter(function(ovej){

    return ovej;
  });
```

Considera una lista/array de ovejas. Cada oveja tiene un nombre y un color. Haz una función que devuelva una lista con todas las ovejas que sean de color rojo y que su nombre contenga las letras n y a, sin importar el orden, las mayúsculas o espacios.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes colocar tu código en vez de imagen? para ayudarte mejor

Comment: const ovejas = [
    { name: 'Noa', color: 'azul' },
    { name: 'Euge', color: 'rojo' },
    { name: 'Navidad', color: 'rojo' },
    { name: 'Ki Na Ma', color: 'rojo'}
  ]

  let ovejasFiltradas = ovejas.filter(function(ovej){

    return ovej;
  });

Comment: Colócalo en la pregunta, para que sea entendible

Comment: `let ovejasFiltradas = ovejas.filter(function(ovej){return /(?=.*a)(?=.*n)/i.test(ovej.name) && ovej.color === 'rojo'; });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aca te dejo un codigo sencillo con **FOR** que te puede servir:

```js
const ovejas = [ { name: 'Noa', color: 'azul' }, { name: 'Euge', color: 'rojo' }, { name: 'Navidad', color: 'rojo' }, { name: 'Ki Na Ma', color: 'rojo'} ];

var contador=0;

function buscar_ovejas()
{
var ovejas_nuevas=[];
for(i=0;i<ovejas.length;i++)
  {
    var nombre=ovejas[i]["name"];
    if(nombre.includes("N") || nombre.includes("n") || nombre.includes("a") || nombre.includes("A"))
    {
        if(ovejas[i]["color"]=="rojo")
        ovejas_nuevas.push(ovejas[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(ovejas_nuevas);
}

buscar_ovejas();
```

Dentro del FOR valido las Letras N y A (Mayúsculas y minúsculas) y ademas el color y los guardo en un array nuevo y lo muestro en consola.

Comment: me funciono, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

> Tambien con filter()

```js
const ovejas = [ 
  { name: 'Noa', color: 'azul' },
  { name: 'Euge', color: 'rojo' }, 
  { name: 'Navidad', color: 'rojo' }, 
  { name: 'Ki Na Ma', color: 'rojo'}
 ];
let ovejasLetra=ovejas.filter(ove=>ove.name.includes("N")
 || ove.name.includes("n") || ove.name.includes("a")
  || ove.name.includes("A"))
let ovejasRojas=ovejasLetra.filter(ove=>ove.color=='rojo');
console.log(ovejasRojas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola acá mi solución:

```
const ovejasFiltradas = ovejas.filter(oveja => oveja.color == "rojo")
  .filter(oveja => (oveja.name.includes("a") || oveja.name.includes("A")) && ((oveja.name.includes("n") || oveja.name.includes("N"))));
```

Comment: _¿Qué hace este código?_ Recuerda que la respuesta no es solo para el OP (autor de la pregunta), sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de [es.so].